# Java Create Out of Memory Instance

Tags: java, weblogic, out-of-memory

I need to create an out of memory instance on purpose for testing purposes. Does anyone know the fastest way to do this?

Comment: *"out of memory instance"*  Is that anything like an Out of Body Experience?  ;)

Comment: @thinksteep On a more serious note, I suspect adding a `String` to an `ArrayList` or `Vector` in a never ending loop would get to an OOME slightly quicker than reading a `File`.  There is an overhead for I/O.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, wouldn't that be stackoverflow error?

Answer (score 15):

Depends what you are trying to do, but this should be enough:

`double[] d = new double[Integer.MAX_VALUE];`

Comment: Yep, got to admit, that is certainly quicker than my looping method.  +1

Comment: Also, use JVM option -Xmx with minimal value of 1m, e.g. `java -Xmx1m Myclass`

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class TestOome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2^20];
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            while (true) {
                list.add("Lollygobblenlissbomb");
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            buffer = null;
            System.err.println(t + " in " + (end-start) + " millis.");
        }
    }
}
```

### Local output

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in 1152 millis.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

run a recursive function that calls itself with no base/anchor case. Each recursive call creates a stack. So that should be fast.

Comment: That's likely to throw a StackOverflow exception, not an OutOfMemory.